# Function Space Generated by Periodic Functions

Tags: functional-analysis

I am considering the set of all periodic functions in one real variable and taking real values. The functions in question do not have to be continuous, nor do they share a commone period. But we do assume that the functions are defined over all of $\mathbb{R}$. It follows that these functions cannot form a real vector space.

My question is: how can we determine if a specific function lies the space generated by the periodic functions above?

For example, one may verify that $y=x$ lies in this space while $y=|x|$ does not. The question looks quite old fashioned yet I failed to find any related literature. Thanks for help!

N.B. About the function $y=x$: let $X=\{X_\alpha\}$ be a Hamel basis for $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. For each $x \in \mathbb{R}$, let $x=\sum r_\alpha X_\alpha$ with $r_\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}$. Let $q(x) = r_\alpha$ for a specific $\alpha$. Assume w.l.o.g. that $X_\alpha =1$. Then, $f_1(x)=q(x)$ and $f_2(x)=x-q(x)$ are both periodic functions while $x = f_1(x) + f_2(x)$.

Comment: The set of all functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bb R$ is certainly a real vecror space; I can't imagine why you think the fact that the functions are defined on the entire line means this is not so.

Comment: My bad. What I meant by "all functions" is actually all periodic functions.

Comment: NOw, talking about the subspace generated by the periodic functions is different. If "generated by" means generated by in the sense of linear algebra then again, this is a vector space. But when you say that $x$ is in the space generated by the periodic functions I wonder what you mean by "generated by", because $x$ is certainly not a linear combination of periodic functions...

Comment: I think we do agree on the term "generated by". The function $y=x$ lies in the space since it can be recovered by a weird periodic function created with the help of the Hamel basis of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Hope I have made myself clear XD

Comment: No, if $x$ is "generated by" the periodic functions I have no idea what you mean, The standard meaning of "generated by" is "is a linear combination of", but that can't be what you mean if$x$ is generated by the periodic functions. Saying it's so because "it can be recovered by a weird periodic function created with the help of the Hamel basis of R over Q." is miles and miles from a "clear" definition of "generated by". (What does "can be recovered from" mean?????????????)

Comment: Got it. I tried to specify the "weird functions" in the updated version of description. Does it make more sense? Thanks, David!

Comment: I didn't believe it but it's so. Any $X_\beta$ with $\beta\ne\alpha$ is a period for $f_1$. Idon't see why $f_2$ is periodic unless you assume (as you can) that $X-\alpha=1$, in which case $X_\apha$ is a period of $f_2$.

Comment: sorry, I have nothing to say about how to recognize that a function is a linear combination ofperiodic functions; evidently I'm not very good at that myself...

Comment: YES! That's exactly what I did! :D Thanks anyway!

Comment: ??? no, that's not exactly what you did, at least in your post - I looked carefully to see if you assumed $X_\alpha=1$. You didn't assume that; then why _is_ $f_2$ periodic?

Comment: My bad... I meant to say that $q(x) = r_\alpha X_\alpha$ though.

Comment: ok, that does it too.